# javascript : how to resize window when there are many frames

Tags: javascript, html, resize, window

I want to resize window within multiple frames

but it's not working because of frames.

example)
frame.html

```
<html>
  <frameset cols="15%,*">
   <frame src="a.html" name = "a"> 
    <frame src="b.html" name="b"> 
   </frameset> 
 </HTML>
```

---

b.html

```
<html>
  <script>
        function temp(){
         document.href.location = "c.html";
        }
   </script>
   <body>
    b
    <input type = button onclick = temp()>
   </body>
   </HTML>
```

---

c.html

```
<html>
<script type = "text/javascript">
     window.onload = function(){
     window.resizeTo(300,300);
     }
 </script>
 <body>
 c
</body>
</HTML>
```

---

I want to resize the window if I go to page C, but it's not working because of frames. 
So, I use the target like
`top.location.href = "url"` but it ignores `a.html`.
How can I solve the problem?/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to resize the outmost window, then instead of `window.resizeTo(300,300);` do `top.window.resizeTo(300,300);`. If the browser window really will be resized, depends on user settings of a browser.

If you want to resize frames, you have to change the value of `cols` attribute/property of the corresponding `frameset`.

Notice also, that `document.href.location` should be `document.location.href`